# Layout resize delay when soft keyboard appears

Tags: android, android-layout, keyboard

I have set the soft input keyboard to be visible and resizing my layout for a specific activity in my app, by setting the value `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"` in the manifest.
Everything works as expected but when the activity is created my layout gets resized after about a one second delay after the keyboard appeared. This is not a big problem but it isn't great for the user experience. If I close then the keyboard manually and reopen it, there is no delay concerning the resize of the layout.
Does anyone have an idea of what's going wrong ?

Comment: have you check on device or emulator ?

Comment: I have checked on device only